# Apache Drill - Not listing tables in Hive DB

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-drill

I have created the necessary storage plugins and the relevant databases in hive show up when issuing the show database command.

When using one of the hive databases though using the use command, I found that I cannot select any tables which are within that database. Looking further, when issuing the show table command, no tables within that database show up via Apache Drill whereas they appear fine in Hive.

Is there anything I am missing by any chance in terms of granting permission via Hive to any user? How exactly does Apache Drill connect to Hive to run the relevant jobs?

Appreciate your responses.

Comment: Your Hive metastore is wrong in Drill properties maybe... Also, I'm not sure Drill supports the "show tables" command.

Comment: Agree, with @cricket_007, apparently problem with Hive metastore config in storage plugin. Regarding show tables command, it works fine for Hive tables.

Comment: @cricket_007 - I had tried both the following metastore URIs :- "hive.metastore.uris": "thrift://sandbox.hortonworks.com:9083" and  "hive.metastore.uris": "thrift://localhost:9083" but yet facing the same issue. "hive.metastore.uris": "thrift://sandbox.hortonworks.com:9083" was what i obtained when digging into the hive configs via ambari. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Where are you running the Drill process? From within HDP or your host machine? I know that HDP does not offer Drill and Hive LLAP claims to be faster anyway

Comment: I tried using the Web UI which i spinned up using the drillbit.sh command as well as the sqlline command line interface where I am faced with the same issue. I am using the HortonWorks Sandbox 2.5 VM.

Answer (score 0):

`Show tables;` will not list hive tables as of now.  It's better to create **views** on top of hive tables. These Views will show up on `show tables;` command.

Comment: It can show tables in Hive, see 4 paragraph:
https://drill.apache.org/docs/show-tables/#examples